# preparar Iframe or embed responsivo para mobile

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, iframe, layout-responsivo

Pessoal tenho um projeto c# MVC5 e meu cenário é o seguinte:
Tenho que abrir em uma url amigável uma serie grande de páginas (com conteúdo de mídia) feitas por terceiros. Uma de cada vez claro (de acordo com o parâmetro recebido)
Criei então essa URL amigável e na minha View carrego essa página em um iframe:

```
<iframe id='TourVirtual' runat='server' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen=allowFullScreen src="@ViewBag.Link" gesture="media"></iframe>
```

Funciona legal no desktop, mas a responsividade da página que fica dentro do iframe não funciona de acordo, ela deveria reajustar o tamanho de botões e imagens de maneira mais adequada a tela pequena.
Como sou uma ameba em relação a css... queria saber:

**Como preparar a página filha para ser carregada em um iframe de forma que ela mantenha a responsividade?
Ou talvez essa "preparação" não seja necessário se eu carregar a página de outra maneira. Aceito sugestões.**

**UPLOAD----------------------------------------**

Eu cheguei a tentar carregar a página pelo back-end (razor). com este código:

```
@{
    string URL = ViewBag.Link;
    //bool HomeH1 = Request.Url.Segments.Length == 1;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    var header = client.DownloadString(URL);
}
@Html.Raw(header)
```

Mas não tive sucesso pois o caminho para os css e js da propia página é passado de forma indireta /arquivoccdoscara.css aí ele pega a url do meu site e ferra tudo.
E não posso alterar esse caminhos, porque como disse esse materia é produzido por terceiros e já existem dezenas (talvez centenas prontos) então mesmo que me desse autorização para alterar as rotas dos js/css deles não seria viável.

**UPLOAD----------------------------------------**

O problema que estou tento é melhor exemplificado nas imagens a seguir:

Aqui como deveria carregar (quando acesso diretamente) [screenshot.net/pt/79q54hd](http://screenshot.net/pt/79q54hd)

Aqui é como está sendo carregada (quando uso o iframe) [screenshot.net/pt/8gowrbw](http://screenshot.net/pt/8gowrbw)

Reparem que ao invés de seguir a formatação própria de dispositivos moveis, o conteúdo apenas encolhe de tamanho.

Comment: Primeiro, porque há necessidade de carregar dentro de uma iframe? os dados estão vindo do mesmo  site ou de outro ? caso seja do  mesmo, pode carregar via ajax (jquery).
Creio que o problema da responsavidade não esteja em ser carregado dentro de uma  iframe, mas  sim  nos @media do arquivo css,  que talvez não estejam setados para determinado portview

Comment: @MarcosBrinner iframe, foi apenas a única maneira que encontrei para o link não ficar /uploadfiles/agenciax/569896. Essas páginas são compilados de fotos que permitem navegação como no google street view. Temos uma para cada imovel. Ao clicar no link, abro em uma nova guia com uma url amigavél meusite/tourvirtual/nomedoimovel e jogo a página no iframe que ocupa 100% do espaço de tela no navegador. Eu cheguei até a tentar outra coisa via back-end... vou adicionar agora ao final dessa pergunta.

Comment: Você só irá conseguir deixar responsivo caso a página que esteja sendo carregada no `iframe` esteja preparada para ser responsiva.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Exato, como disse o css da pagina deve ter suporte a dimensões do portview media screen de uma olhada aqui  AlamO caso não saiba como funciona https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp , mas  para isso você precisa ter acesso aos dados da pagina que está carregando.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus a página pai onde carrego iframe é responsiva. tanto que no geral a pagina se adapta ao tamanho. Só que ela faz isso reduzindo o tamanho do conteudo. aí os botoes e opções de navegação ficam muito pequenas. Eu acredito que a pagina filha que estou carregando no iframe não esteja conseguindo perceber que está carregada em um tamanho menor e assim não se adapta. Isso faz sentido? Vou ilustrar colocando aqui o resultado q obtenho acessando a pagina filha diretamente (ou seja como deve ficar) e o resultado que obtenho acessando via iframe

Comment: @JorgeMatheus vejam aqui meu problema: Este link é da página carregada diretamente (sem o iframe) é assim q deveria ficar: https://screenshot.net/pt/79q54hd
E esta aqui é como está sendo carregada (quando uso o iframe) https://screenshot.net/pt/8gowrbw

Comment: @MarcosBrinner veja nos links do ultimo comentário a pagina como está carregando no iframe e como deveria estar na realidade (quando carrego diretamente ou seja sem o iframe). Repare que os controles ficam diminutos

Comment: tente definir o  meta viewport dentro das tags header da pagina que está no  iframe

Comment: de uma olha em  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: @MarcosBrinner era isso mesmo. Obrigado aos que colaboraram e tiveram paciência.

Answer (score 1):

A solução foi adicionar um viewport
na página que ** contém ** o iframe. A que está contida já  tinha.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
```